# moving / scrolling up and down on three JTable simultanously.

Tags: java, swing, listener, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have three different jtable on three diffenernt jscrollpane - one next to the other.
I successfuly written some code that makes them all scroll together when I scroll the mouse wheel.
I inherrited JScrollpane and overriden its processMouseWheelEvent methos as follows:

```
  public void processMouseWheelEvent(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    ...
    if (e.getSource() == this) {
        for (BTSJScrollPane other : effected) {
            other.processMouseWheelEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have canelled the pageup pagedown using

```
 final InputMap inputMap =   
             comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("PAGE_DOWN"), EMPTY);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("PAGE_UP"), EMPTY);

    comp.getActionMap().put(EMPTY, emptyAction);
```

But,
my only problem now is that when the user clicks up and down, they dont go together but rather scroll indipently.
Any suggestions ?
So far I wrote in my scrollpane something like

```
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (thisIsThesourceTable) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 38 || e.getKeyCode() == 40) {

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But :
1. is there a better way?
2. maybe I should do it somehow in the actionMap?
3. how do I pass the key up/down event to the other scrollpane?
4. can I know if I am near the end of the viewing part in the scroll pane? is it needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1, 2, & 3: You should use listeners on the scrollbars so it works with mouse, keyboard, and scrollbar interaction.  That way you won't need key or mouse listeners. Here is one way:

```
scroll1.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
       scroll2.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(e.getValue());
    }
});
```

4: Look at JScrollPane's getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximumSize() and getModel() to find out if you're near the end.

Comment: Wow. a. If I could have given you more point I would. b. I have deleted now a lot of code with this one line. c. I dont need now answer to no. 4.. d. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just glad to give back to the community that has helped me so much over the years.