# find if my component is an ancestor of other component

Tags: java, swing

I implement

```
  @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
```

in my jscrollpane.
when I am evaluating

```
e.getSource()
```

I get the jtable that is under the JScrollPane.

how do I know that it is in my hierarchy ?
(I call other jscrollpane functions, passing the keyevent, and I dont want recursions)

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Overriding dispatchKeyEvent is generally unnecessary and the wrong way of doing things.

Comment: trying to do this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282064/moving-scrolling-up-and-down-on-three-jtable-simultanously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this?:

```
SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, jtable);
```

Or if you want to check for a given instance:

```
SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(jtable, aParentOfJTable);
```

If not then I don't understand your question.

Comment: thanks. SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(jtable, aParentOfJTable);
This did the trick for me